# Custom Keyboard Layout Not Working

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I made a keyboard layout for Russian, however when I went to compile it, it said that I need to be logged in as the admin to do it, so I asked the admin to help me and when he did it, it worked! However, when I logged into my own account, the layout was not present in the options. Has anyone ever experienced such a problem before?
If so, how did you fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Is your question really "Has anyone ever experienced such a problem before?"? The answer is either "yes" or "no", but is this really what you want to know? "How can I make the layout appear in options?" seems way more constructive. Please [edit] and improve the question, also provide more details. What is your OS? How did you make the keyboard layout? How did the admin compile it? What exactly do you mean by "it worked", since it did not work for you?

Comment: You need to talk with your admin about this.